# OpenCV's createsamples tool fails to use all samples when converting info file to vec file

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I've created an info text file by using `opencv_annotation` tool, with around 300 image, and some contain multiple ROIs (Region of Interests). The following is an example output of the file, with dots indicating many lines with the same format:

```
positives\1\105.png 1 9 10 17 14
...
positives\2\003.png 2 14 2 5 7 11 18 8 9
...
positives\3\045.png 3 21 9 7 9 13 10 9 11 7 15 6 7
```

However, `opencv_annotation` then crashes, with the error `assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) ...`, and only a fraction (~200 out of ~600) of the ROIs in the info text file were placed into the vec file, verified by how `opencv_traincascade` reports insufficient samples when using the parameter `-numPos 500` when attempting to use the vec file.

Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this is that a ROI that was improperly defined while creating the samples.
In my specific case, this specific line was found:

```
positives\2\005.png 2 9 6 6 7 0 0 0 0
```

Recall how the format of these files:

```
[filename] [# of objects] [[x y width height] [... 2nd object] ...]
```

In my case, the specified region had a width and length of 0 pixels, which causes `opencv_createsamples` to crash with the very error. Simply removing the object data and decrementing the `[# of objects]` by one solved this issue, like so:

```
positives\2\005.png 1 9 6 6 7
```

Additionally, one should also look out for values that reach out of bounds, such as the following:

```
positives\2\005.png 2 9 6 6 7 -5 0 3 2
positives\2\005.png 2 9 6 6 7 30 30 200 300
positives\2\005.png 2 9 6 6 7 35 35 3 5
```

In the first example, no point should be negative. In the second example, our `.png` file is only 32 x 32 pixels large, so a ROI cannot have a `width` and `height` of 200 and 300, respectively. Finally, in the last example, the `x` and `y` positions are out of bounds of our image.